# Build label_image tensorflow example with Windows10

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow

I built tensorflow following every bit of instruction [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md). 
 The build with VS2015 x64 looks fine, but when compiling the `tensorflow\examples\label_image` sample I have many errors:

```
\tensorflow\third_party\eigen3\unsupported\eigen\cxx11\tensor(1): fatal error C1014: too many include files: depth = 1024
```

Fixing it with `a #pragma once`, then I got that this (and many like this)

```
template <>
struct NumTraits<QInt8> : GenericNumTraits<int8_t> {};
```

gives this error:

`\tensorflow\third_party\eigen3\unsupported\eigen\cxx11\src\fixedpoint\fixedpointtypes.h(27): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition`

I also miss the file

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/image_ops.h"
```

Did anyone succeed to built (and link...) this sample?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but this article cleared it up:

https://joe-antognini.github.io/machine-learning/windows-tf-project

Your include directories need to be in the correct order, specifically

{your path}\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\external\eigen_archive

must be listed before

{your path}\tensorflow\third_party\eigen3

Answer (score 0):

may be your include path is wrong. in my project i copy all incloud path in _beam_search_ops project to my project. then the problem is solved